# The root path "/" does not match the reactjs declared route on server side rendering, when webpack middleware is used

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

While studying Reactjs Server Side Rendering, on a node Express web server, and Webpack middleware, I'm finding hard to understand why the root route "/" matching component is not passed into the html, while nested "/foobar" works fine (and you see the parents too).

If the webpack middleware's removed, the path "/" returns the match reactjs route.

Please find the source below, have in mind that there's a lot of testing and seeing and it's not quality code.

The Webpack development configuration file:

```js
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './js/index.js'
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.html'),
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
      }
    }),
    // enable HMR globally
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // prints more readable module names in the browser console on HMR updates
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ]
}
```

The Reactjs Router related components.

The Rootjs:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Router } from 'react-router'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import routes from './routes'

const Root = ({store, history}) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        { routes }
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default Root
```

The Routes:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router'
import App from './containers/app'
import Foobar from './containers/foobar'

export default (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <Route path='foobar' component={Foobar} />
  </Route>
)
```

The Server.js:

```js
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import superagent from 'superagent'
import chalk from 'chalk'

import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import routes from './src/js/routes'

import configureStore from './src/js/store'
import App from './src/js/containers/app'

const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 3000
var serverInstance = null
var dist = path.join(__dirname, ('dist' + (process.env.NODE_ENV ? '/' + process.env.NODE_ENV : 'staging')))
var config = null
var fs = require('fs')
var htmlTemplateString = ''

/**
 * Environment settings
 */
if (['staging', 'production'].indexOf(process.env.NODE_ENV) > -1) {
  console.log('break 1')
  dist = path.resolve(__dirname, process.env.NODE_ENV)
  config = require('../config')
  htmlTemplateString = fs.readFileSync(dist + '/index.html', 'utf-8')
} else {
  console.log('break 2')
  config = require('./config')
  htmlTemplateString = fs.readFileSync('./dist/production/index.html', 'utf-8')
}

/**
 * Process error handling
 */
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  throw err
})

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  serverInstance.close()
  process.exit(0)
})

/**
 * The Cross origin resource sharing rules
 */
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  next()
})

/**
 * Health check
 */
app.use('/healthcheck', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    'env': {
      'NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV
    }
  })
  res.end()
})

router.use('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  superagent
    .get('https://jsonip.com/')
    .end((err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('api test err', err)
      }
      res.send(response.body)
    })
})

// HMR only in development
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'staging') {
  console.log('Development environment: Starting webPack middleware...')

  const webpack = require('webpack')
  const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
  const webpackDevConfig = require('./webpack.dev.config')
  const compiler = webpack(webpackDevConfig)

  var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')
  var devMiddleware = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: webpackDevConfig.output.publicPath,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    }
  })

  router.use(devMiddleware)

  router.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
    log: console.log
  }))

  // Production needs physical files! (built via separate process)
  router.use('/assets', express.static(dist))

  // any other is mapped here
  router.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('req.url: ', req.url)
    match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
      if (props) {
        const preloadedState = {'foobar': 1}
          // Create a new Redux store instance
        const store = configureStore(preloadedState)
          // Render the component to a string
        const myAppHtml = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props} />)

          // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
        const finalState = store.getState()
          // Send the rendered page back to the client
        let html = htmlTemplateString.replace('<div id="app">', '<div id="app">' + myAppHtml)

          // Paste the state into the html
        const preloadedStateScript = `<script>window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(finalState).replace(/</g, '\\x3c')}</script>`
        html = html.replace('</head>', preloadedStateScript)
        res.send(html)
      } else {
        res.status(404).send('Not found')
      }
    })
  })
}

app.disable('x-powered-by')

app.use('/', router)

serverInstance = app.listen(port, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error) // eslint-disable-line no-console
  }
  console.log(chalk.green('[' + config.build_name + '] listening on port ' + port + '!'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought that had something to do with where the webpack middleware's set, but there's a typo somewhere in the initial code, so had to refactor and it works server side now:

```
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import superagent from 'superagent'
import chalk from 'chalk'

import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import routes from './src/js/routes'

import configureStore from './src/js/store'

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 3000
var serverInstance = null
var dist = path.join(__dirname, ('dist' + (process.env.NODE_ENV ? '/' + process.env.NODE_ENV : 'staging')))
var config = null
var fs = require('fs')
var htmlTemplateString = ''

const webpack = require('webpack')
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
const webpackDevConfig = require('./webpack.dev.config')
const compiler = webpack(require('./webpack.dev.config'))
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')

config = require('./config')
htmlTemplateString = fs.readFileSync('./dist/production/index.html', 'utf-8')

/**
 * Process error handling
 */
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  throw err
})

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  serverInstance.close()
  process.exit(0)
})

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: webpackDevConfig.output.publicPath,
  stats: {
    colors: true
  }
}))

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
  log: console.log
}))

/**
 * The Cross origin resource sharing rules
 */
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  next()
})

/**
 * Health check
 */
app.use('/healthcheck', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    'env': {
      'NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV
    }
  })
  res.end()
})

app.use('/api/test', (req, res) => {
  superagent
    .get('https://jsonip.com/')
    .end((err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('api test err', err)
      }
      res.send(response.body)
    })
})

app.use('/assets', express.static(dist))

// any other is mapped here
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('req.url', req.url)
  match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, props) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (props) {
      const preloadedState = {'foobar': 1}
            // Create a new Redux store instance
      const store = configureStore(preloadedState)
            // Render the component to a string
      const myAppHtml = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props} />)

            // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
      const finalState = store.getState()
            // Send the rendered page back to the client
      let html = htmlTemplateString.replace('<div id="app">', '<div id="app">' + myAppHtml)

            // Paste the state into the html
      const preloadedStateScript = `<script>window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(finalState).replace(/</g, '\\x3c')}</script>`
      html = html.replace('</head>', preloadedStateScript)
      res.status(200).send(html)
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  })
})

serverInstance = app.listen(port, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error) // eslint-disable-line no-console
  }
  console.log(chalk.green('[' + config.build_name + '] listening on port ' + port + '!'))
})
```